# To create multiple activities or not?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-ndk, android-manifest

I am creating an application for contact-book. I wish to know whether it is valid to create multiple activities in the application or creating a single activity for all screens in an application.

I am not sure, which is the standard process.

It would be helpful if anyone provides a valid-link for this, where the standards are defined.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you create multiple activities - the Back button will be handled automatically. Also it makes the code more logical and clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to carefully identify your requirement.

You should consider creating **Fragments** when you are creating your application.
Number of Activity depends upon number of different tasks you want to perform in your application
for example
in you contact application if you are working with

1. Contact listing page
2. Contact detail page

this can be accompalished by just **one activity** and **two fragments** :)

Fragments will also help you to setup your UI on tablet mode... in one screen itself under landscape orientation.

But yet again! it totally depends upon your requirement of application.

**THERE IS NO SET RULE!** that's what great about Android. :)

Answer (score 1):

Activities designed to be decoupled from each other.
You should look at activities as screens, and create different activity for each different screen.
You can reuse the same activity if you more than one mode in which it can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer activity per screen (Which will be little bit clean in code perspective) . Somewhere in andriod documentation also it says same.

Comment: can you please let me know about the link in android-documentation where this is mentioned ?

Comment: Here is the link, this may be specific to Tabhost ( if each tab provides a distinct user activity, then it probably makes sense to use a separate Activity).http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html